# Get "i" in asynchrounous request

Tags: javascript

I have a view-request which returns amount X and will then fire a function X times through a for-loop. It works everything but due to the asynchronous request, I do not get the correct i-value that the function/request was fired with. The (javascript) code:

```
X = [0,2,4,6]
for(var i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
    // i is the user ID
    contract.getUser(i, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
        /////
    }
    else if (result) {
            // I want to return the current i-value (loop-value),
            // But due to the asynchronous request, it always returns the 
            // last value (in our example 4)
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine (I get the user) but I can't redirect to for example url.com/user/ID because the ID (i) is always the same.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the same `i` is being captured by all the callback functions, so they all see the same value when they're ultimately invoked.

One popular workaround is to use an [immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) as follows:

```js
X = [0,2,4,6]

for (var i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
    (function (n) { // function is defined here
        contract.getUser(n, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                ...
            }
            else if (result) {
                console.log(n);
            }
        });
    })(i); // and immediately executed here, with a specific i value passed in
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! contract.getUser(i..) even works, I just can't work with it as the result is showed only later. But this solved it!

Comment: Yes, `i` in the call to `getUser` is fine because it happens synchronously (so it receives the current value of `i` for that iteration of the loop). It's just the callback that's problematic because it sees the current value of `i` at that time, which is after the loop has finished.